# In an Expo project : conditional navigation probleme

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit, react-native-navigation

Hello Everyone I am a React-native beginner,
So what I want to achieve is to make the user go to the login Screenthe first time he opens the app once the login is successful want him to be redirected to the home page and I do have a ButtomNav nested inside StackNavigation, I also want to store the user details with AsyncStorage
LoginScreen.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../slices/userSlice";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.userLogin)




  const submitHandler = () => {
    try {
         dispatch(login({ email, password }));
         AsyncStorage.setItem("@user", JSON.stringify(user));
         navigation.navigate("Nav", { screen: 'Home' });
      } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };



  return (
    <View className="w-full h-full justify-center items-center">
      <View className="w-5/6 flex flex-col justify-center items-center" >
        <Text className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-sky-800 mb-6"> Login</Text>
        <View className=" w-11/12 bg-sky-200 p-3 rounded mb-4" >
          <TextInput            
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View  className=" w-11/12 bg-sky-200 p-3 rounded" >
          <TextInput           
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={submitHandler} className="flex justify-center items-center w-3/5 bg-blue-800 h-12 mt-8 rounded-lg" >
          <Text className=" text-white font-extrabold" >LOGIN </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};


export default Login;
```

and this is the App.js file

```
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { StatusBar, ActivityIndicator, View, Button } from "react-native";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import SingleProductScreen from "./screens/SingleProductScreen";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import Client from "./screens/Client";
import Cart from "./screens/Cart";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { logout } from "./slices/userSlice";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const BottomTap = createBottomTabNavigator();

function ButtomNav() {

  return (
    <BottomTap.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#0A1886" },
        headerTintColor: "white",
      }}
    >
      <BottomTap.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTap.Screen
        name="Clients"
        component={Client}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="people" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTap.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={Cart}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="cart" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
     
    </BottomTap.Navigator>
  );
}

function Root() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userLogedIn, setUserLogedIn] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUserDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user");
        if (user) {
          setUserLogedIn(user);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    checkUserToken();
  }, [userLogedIn]); 

  

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#0A1886" },
            headerTintColor: "white",
          }}
        >
          {userLogedIn !== null ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Nav"
                component={ButtomNav}
                options={{
                  headerRight: () => (
                    <Button title="Log out" onPress={logoutHandler} />
                  ),
                  headerShown: false,
                }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={SingleProductScreen} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen 
              name="Login"
              component={Login}
              options={{
                title: "Sign in",
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is what I got so far, for now when I first open the app the login screen does git render first and when I log in I don't get redirected to the home screen as expected instead I get an error that says

```
 ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Nav"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Nav'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

so can anyone help me to find a better way to handle this navigation problem

Comment: Somewhere in your project, you're calling `navigate('Nav')`. Find that and change it to a screen you have defined, like 'Home'. If that's not enough to solve your problem, post what happens when you dispatch your login call.

Comment: it is actually on the login screen and it goes like this **navigation.navigate("Nav", { screen: 'Home' });** because Home screen is nested in the Nav

Comment: Where are you calling the stack Nav?

Comment: in App.js I have a Root function which is a Stack Navigation and the first screen is a nested BottomNavigation

Comment: Add it to the post please, can't tell what's wrong if we can't see it

Comment: I added It navigation.navigate("Nav", { screen: 'Home' }), its in the loginScreen.js